# Running a command in Powershell and running the exe gives different results

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, executable, perforce

This is really odd.

I have a so called `Perforce Helix server` on my `Windows 2016` server.

Now on this server there is an `exe` called `p4d` now if i go to the `Powershell` and run `p4d` it runs the command starts the "correct" server and i am able to connect and see all my users.

If i then stop the command and go to the folder where the exe is located and run that a completely different server is starting meaning that all our code base and users are different.

I have attempted to find out of there are multiple `p4d` exe's on my machine however only 1 could be located. And true enough if I run the command:

```
get-command p4d
```

It returns the actual location of the `exe` that when is run opens a different server.

Can anyone tell me what the problem might be? Has anyone faced a similar issue? This is a huge problem because it means that i cannot make the it to a service and run it on startup.

Comment: Are you sure that it is different EXEs, and not something different about the environment of how the commands are getting run?  Does the powershell session have different permissions, different environment variables, or something else?

Comment: @Zoredache Can you tell me how i can check those things? then i will check it out

Comment: Are you making the second invocation from Explorer GUI, Cmd, somewhere else? Is the powershell running with/without "as administrator"? Try making explorer launch with "as administrator" if that is how powershell prompt is being launched.

Comment: PowerShell does not run executables from the current directory by default. If you intend to start `p4d.exe` from the current directory, you need to type `.\p4d` (or `./p4d`), not just `p4d`.